# Can anyone tell me why this isn't giving any output?

Tags: javascript

`This is for a Javascript exercise:  User inputs 4 GPAS, then output descending order, Highest & Lowest GPS, GPAS above 3.4 and average GPA.   I can input the 4 GPAS but then it is blank?'

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>JS Lesson 
        5A</title>
    /head>
    <body>
        <h2>Class GPAs</h2>
        <div id="output"></div>
        <script>
            var gpas = [3.4, 3.12, 3.333, 2.5, 1.9, 3.94, 2.1, 4, 3.11];
            var out = "";
            for(var i=0; i < gpas.length; i++)
            {
                out += gpas[i];
                out += "<br/>";
            }
            document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = out;
            var total = 0;
            for(var i=0; i < gpas.length; i++)
            {
                var total += gpas[i];
                out += "<br/";
            }      
            var average = total/gpas.length;
                out += "Class Average GPA: " + average;
            document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = out;
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `var total += gpas[i];` is invalid syntax. Always check your console for errors before posting questions, you'll save yourself (and others) time and headaches

Answer (score 0):

You have a simple syntax error on the line `var total += gpas[i];`.

The `var` keyword on this line means that you define a new variable called `total` on every loop iteration, which is obviously not what you want. Just remove the `var` keyword and it will work like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this might be the solution to your problem. Your *syntax* error should be this `var total += gpas[i]`; since you have already declared a `total` variable outside to your *loop* don't do that again on your inside *loop* w/ a `var` it's redundant. Then next should be this `out += "Class Average GPA: " + average;` behold that your **out** variable is not a `number` it's a `string` type so you must avoid of doing this stuff `+=` it's a `number` type only to works you must be aware of that. Thanks

```js
  var gpas = [3.4, 3.12, 3.333, 2.5, 1.9, 3.94, 2.1, 4, 3.11];
  var out = "";
  for(var i=0; i < gpas.length; i++)
  {
    out += gpas[i];
    out += "<br/>";
  }

  /* document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = out; */

 var total = 0;
  for(var i=0; i < gpas.length; i++)
  {
    total += gpas[i];
    out += "<br/";
  }      

  var average = total/gpas.length;

  out = "Class Average GPA: " + average;
  document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = out;
```

```html
<h2>Class GPAs</h2>
<div id="output"></div>
```